# Empty results using R scripts in QGIS

Tags: qgis, r, qgis-processing

Using QGIS, after run R script like Histogram it returns an empty result in "Results Viewer" window and no image are created inside html file.

Any ideia of missing configuration or package install? By the way, I'm unable to update R scripts.

(QGIS 2.18.21, Linux Mint Cinnamon)

[image]

Comment: Looks like your R script did not work, but the line `##showplots` had produced a blank html output anyway. Can you post the full code?

Comment: After a log review I found this:
...
'x' must be numeric
Calls: hist -> hist -> hist.default
Execution halted
...
And I find that some field type are 'qlonglong'. It is a shape saved after a table join. I tested using another field (integer) and it was ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a log review I found this:

> 'x' **must be numeric**
>   Calls: hist -> hist -> hist.default
>   Execution halted

And I found that some field type are 'qlonglong'. It is a shape saved after a table join. I tested using another field (integer) and it was ok.